# How to use AWS amplify API in postman?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-amplify

I have to use below inbuilt functions of APIs but how can I use that function to create dynamic sub domain?

It meant, what will be host name for that? and how can I pass request object?
POST /apps/appId/domains HTTP/1.1
what will be the Request URI for that?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDomainAssociation.html

If anyone have knowledge about it and then please help me.

Comment: Did you resolve it? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to appSync aws services to see your apis created by amplify and there you will find URLs e apikeys to be used to connect to AWS amplify by postman or any other client.